# Jni crashes while recording and converting speech in android

Tags: android

I did  audio recorder and convert audio file into codec for storing them on my server. I achieved successfully, but sometimes i got Fatal signal 11, thread 15922 (Thread-3263). I don't know why. Please help me.

here is my stack trace:

```
09-09 10:23:45.009: I/System.out(15457): 1028
09-09 10:23:45.009: E/(15457): Available MB : 534
09-09 10:23:45.009: I/System.out(15457): 8192
09-09 10:23:45.464: I/System.out(15457): test recorder
09-09 10:23:45.464: I/System.out(15457): 8192  8192
09-09 10:23:45.509: I/System.out(15457): 1028
09-09 10:23:45.509: E/(15457): Available MB : 534
09-09 10:23:45.509: I/System.out(15457): 8192
09-09 10:23:45.964: I/System.out(15457): test recorder
09-09 10:23:45.964: I/System.out(15457): 8192  8192
09-09 10:23:46.009: I/System.out(15457): 1028
09-09 10:23:46.009: E/(15457): Available MB : 534
09-09 10:23:46.009: I/System.out(15457): 8192
09-09 10:23:46.517: I/System.out(15457): test recorder
09-09 10:23:46.517: I/System.out(15457): 8192  8192
09-09 10:23:46.566: I/System.out(15457): 1028
09-09 10:23:46.567: E/(15457): Available MB : 534
09-09 10:23:46.567: I/System.out(15457): 8192
09-09 10:23:46.772: I/System.out(15457): mss->0
09-09 10:23:46.774: I/System.out(15457):  rec is stoped
09-09 10:23:46.774: V/AudioRecord(15457): stop
09-09 10:23:46.920: I/System.out(15457): test recorder
09-09 10:23:46.920: I/System.out(15457): 8192  4096
09-09 10:23:46.921: V/AudioRecord(15457): stop
09-09 10:23:46.921: V/AudioRecord(15457): stop
09-09 10:23:46.921: V/AudioRecord(15457): stop
09-09 10:23:46.922: D/dalvikvm(15457): threadid=25: bye!
09-09 10:23:46.923: D/dalvikvm(15457): create interp thread : stack size=32KB
09-09 10:23:46.923: D/dalvikvm(15457): create new thread
09-09 10:23:46.924: D/dalvikvm(15457): new thread created
09-09 10:23:46.924: D/dalvikvm(15457): update thread list
09-09 10:23:46.924: D/dalvikvm(15457): threadid=25: interp stack at 0x5e635000
09-09 10:23:46.924: D/dalvikvm(15457): threadid=25: created from interp
09-09 10:23:46.924: D/dalvikvm(15457): start new thread
09-09 10:23:46.929: D/dalvikvm(15457): threadid=25: notify debugger
09-09 10:23:46.930: D/dalvikvm(15457): threadid=25 (Thread-3266): calling run()
09-09 10:23:46.946: I/SurfaceTextureClient(15457): [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x5f013248) fps:0.46, dur:4349.48, max:4276.31, min:73.16
09-09 10:23:46.960: I/System.out(15457): 84
09-09 10:23:46.963: A/libc(15457): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000004 (code=1), thread 15922 (Thread-3263)
09-09 10:23:46.964: A/libc(15457): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xa0a25f6e (code=1), thread 15933 (Thread-3266)
09-09 10:23:46.969: D/dalvikvm(15457): create interp thread : stack size=32KB
09-09 10:23:46.969: D/dalvikvm(15457): create new thread
09-09 10:23:46.969: D/dalvikvm(15457): new thread created
09-09 10:23:46.969: D/dalvikvm(15457): update thread list
09-09 10:23:46.969: D/dalvikvm(15457): threadid=26: interp stack at 0x5e63d000
09-09 10:23:46.969: D/dalvikvm(15457): threadid=26: created from interp
09-09 10:23:46.969: D/dalvikvm(15457): start new thread
09-09 10:23:46.970: D/dalvikvm(15457): threadid=26: notify debugger
09-09 10:23:46.970: D/dalvikvm(15457): threadid=26 (Thread-3267): calling run()
09-09 10:23:46.970: D/dalvikvm(15457): threadid=26: exiting
09-09 10:23:46.970: D/dalvikvm(15457): threadid=26: bye!
09-09 10:23:46.999: V/InputMethodManager(15457): focusOut: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{422494a8 VFE..... RF...... 0,0-480,558} mServedView=com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{422494a8 VFE..... RF...... 0,0-480,558} winFocus=false
```

java code:

```
while (isRecording && recorder != null) {
    try {

        long availMem = checkMemoryStatus();
        if (availMem >= 10) {
            setRecordingAvail(true);
            // ]
            System.out.println(bufferSize);
            if (recorder != null
                    && (bufferReadResult = recorder.read(
                            bufferS, 0, bufferSize)) > 0) {

                if (bufferReadResult == AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException(
                            "read() returned AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION");

                } else if (bufferReadResult == AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException(
                            "read() returned AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE");
                } else if (bufferReadResult == AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException(
                            "read() returned AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION");
                }

                System.out.println("test recorder");
                System.out.println(bufferS.length + "  " + bufferReadResult * 2);
                outw.write(toByte(bufferS),

                0, bufferReadResult * 2);
                int encodeSize = speex.encode(bufferS, 0, data, bufferReadResult, data.length);//-->jni call
                System.out.println(encodeSize);

                os.write(data, 0, encodeSize);
            }

        }
    } catch (Exception e){

    }
}
```

jni code

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL  Java_com_emdsys_android_pacs_rest_Speex_encode(JNIEnv *env,
        jobject obj, jshortArray lin, jint offset, jbyteArray encoded,
        jint size, jint max_buffer_size) {

    jshort buffer[enc_frame_size];
    jbyte output_buffer[1024 + 4];
    int nsamples = (size - 1) / enc_frame_size + 1;
    int i, tot_bytes = 0;

    if (!codec_open)
        return 0;

    for (i = 0; i < nsamples; i++) {
        speex_bits_reset(&ebits);
        env->GetShortArrayRegion(lin, offset + i * enc_frame_size,
                enc_frame_size, buffer);
        speex_encode_int(enc_state, buffer, &ebits);

        int nbBytes = speex_bits_write(&ebits, ((char *) output_buffer) + 4,
                1024 - tot_bytes);
        memcpy(output_buffer, &nbBytes, 4);
        int len =
                max_buffer_size >=  tot_bytes + nbBytes + 4?
                        nbBytes + 4 : max_buffer_size - tot_bytes;
        env->SetByteArrayRegion(encoded, tot_bytes, len, output_buffer);
        tot_bytes += nbBytes + 4;
    }

    return (jint) tot_bytes;
}
```

Comment: Looks like a null pointer.  Can you post any code that reproduces the problem?  It's hard to say from just some logs.

Comment: srry for delay, now am posted my java and jni code .